# implicit declaration of function ‘sleep’ when using an example of the vlc library

Tags: c, mp3, libvlc

I am testing the vlc library, to be able to make an mp3 player. I found this example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <vlc/vlc.h>
 
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     libvlc_instance_t * inst;
     libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
     libvlc_media_t *m;
     
     /* Load the VLC engine */
     inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);
  
     /* Create a new item */
     m = libvlc_media_new_location (inst, "http://mycool.movie.com/test.mov");
     //m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "/path/to/test.mov");
        
     /* Create a media player playing environement */
     mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);
     
     /* No need to keep the media now */
     libvlc_media_release (m);
 
 #if 0
     /* This is a non working code that show how to hooks into a window,
      * if we have a window around */
      libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (mp, xid);
     /* or on windows */
      libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (mp, hwnd);
     /* or on mac os */
      libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject (mp, view);
  #endif
 
     /* play the media_player */
     libvlc_media_player_play (mp);
    
     sleep (10); /* Let it play a bit */
    
     /* Stop playing */
     libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);
 
     /* Free the media_player */
     libvlc_media_player_release (mp);
 
     libvlc_release (inst);
 
     return 0;
 }
```

The problem I had when compiling was the following:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:37:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sleep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   37 |      sleep (10); /* Let it play a bit */
```

I tried including the time.h library, but the problem was not solved. Does anyone know what happens? If you could recommend something to me or if you have some information, vlclib examples would appreciate it.Or if you recommend any other bookstore, it would also work for me. Thank you

Comment: try `#include <unistd.h>`

Answer (score 1):

POSIX sleep is [declared in `unistd.h` header](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep), you need to have that included.

Comment: Thank you served me. Sorry to bother you, I get the following error: "segmentation fault ('core' generated)".
Do you know why?

Comment: @Bill no idea..but you should check for the success of the function calls.